# My community licences can't open a specific visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, community, custom-object, permissions

I Have a problem with the org I am working on.
I made a formula that display some links in lead layout. Those links run visualforce pages that run httprequests to trigger webservices.
At first it was for my salesforce agents (it works perfectly !) but now I want to make it available for communities users.

They connect and "work" on a custom login page (I wasn't working at the time it was done). Everything works fine (including opening other VF pages) except opening this visualforce page.
When they try to do so, it display a weird error screen.

> https://myclient.force.com/Partner est en cours de créationRestez en contact.
>   Veuillez envoyez nous un e-mail pour rester en contact.

I guess this is some custom error screen.

Here is what does this page :

First step :

- Check lead
- With apex, query a custom object and find the one related to lead
- display a warning message

Second step (that i can't reach but is in the code) :

- with apex run a http request to a webservice
- modify & update lead.

So here is what I did :

- create a custom community profile to be able to add custom object permission (sf support advice) : read/create/edit/delete (all permissions)
- set all apex available to profile
- set all VF available to profile
- debug log : I can see system.debug log for every page that run, but not this one that trigger the weird screen

At this point I have no idea of what I can do.
I would like to understand what I am missing about permissions. What is the web screen, what does it mean.

Salesforce permission are quite confusing ...

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first thing that i think you should do is to check the url for the page that you are opening. Can you access the page from the community. with the suffix for you community.

Second comment all the code while accessing the community if the Page opens or not. You can add a static text"Hello World".

This will help you isolate the problem.

Let me know your finding so i can help you further.